# How would I go about setting up conditional proxy_cache in nginx for a prerender server

Tags: caching, nginx, prerender

I have a frontend rendered app in angular that needs to be crawlable by our belowed bots. I got it working without cache but when wanting to add caching the conf-file is invalid. I've tried searching for this for way too long now and can't come up with a solution. It seems that you can't set proxy_cache in if statements. So what are my options here or am I going about this the wrong way?

```
server {
    server_name IP;
    add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

    location / {
        access_log off;

        set $prerender 0;
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }
        if ($uri ~ "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff)") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }

        if ($prerender = 1) {
            proxy_cache one;
            proxy_cache_valid 200 30m;
            proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
            proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
            proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
            proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
            proxy_hide_header X-powered-by;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            expires 10m;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; #my prerender node server
        }
        if ($prerender = 0) {
            root /my/static/stuff;
            expires max;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had almost forgotten I asked this question until someone upvoted it.
This is how I ended up solving it (due to the limits of if cases in nginx).

in your nginx.conf

```
proxy_cache_path  /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=prerender:60m max_size=200m inactive=30000m;
upstream prerender_upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 64;
}
```

in your siteconf

```
server {
    server_name IP;
    add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

    location /prerender/ {
        access_log off;
        proxy_cache prerender;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 60s;
        proxy_cache_valid 404 60s;
        proxy_pass http://prerender_upstream/;
        proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
        proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
        proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
        proxy_hide_header X-powered-by;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        expires 60s;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }

    location / {
        access_log off;

        set $prerender 0;
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }
        if ($uri ~ "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff)") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }

        if ($prerender = 1) {
            rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
            proxy_pass http://$host/prerender/http://$host$request_uri;
        }
        if ($prerender = 0) {
            root /my/static/stuff;
            expires max;
        }
    }

}
```

It works really well. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: thanks. is this only for prerender or for all files meteor serves?

Comment: According to this article: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/. The only 100% safe things which may be done inside if in a location context are return and rewrite.  I doubt the proxy_pass in if block will always work.